# Identify HE-AAC audio sampling frequency

Tags: audio, aac, mpeg

I am parsing mpeg2 and mpeg4 AV files and in these files there are PMT tables that hold the information about all the elementary streams. Some of the streams are audio with HE-AAC.

For those streams, there is a descriptor (in the pmt table) with descriptor tag 0x2B which implies the stream is representing HE-AAC.

How do I extract the sampling frequency for that stream?

Answer (score 0):

Its not in the PMT. Its in the ADTS header on every aac frame.